# Data from store not reactive in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

This is my first attempt at building a web app with Vuejs. I've been trying to get data from an external JSON API and display it on my app. The JSON fetch etc is working fine. but I can't get the data to be displayed reactively on my component.

As you can read in `Appraisal.js` given an API `link` some data is populated in `Appraisal.app_data`. The data always has an array called `items` (that's just how the API is. I'll add validation later). As a proof of concept I'm trying to display the number of elements in the `items` array.

Since other components in my app will also use this data, I'm using an external `store` as the data source everywhere. One of the components calls `Appraisal.setLink()` on getting some user input. That part is working as expected. However the DOM contents don't change at all.

I referred to [State Management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html) for setting up the external store. I also referred to some other answers on StackOverflow with a similar issue and got the following suggestions:

1. The data should be initialized to undefined or null instead of `{}` for reactivity to work.
2. Properties of objects are not reactive. But by my understanding this was changed in Vue3 where it doesn't matter because proxies are in use. Either way I tried using the `Object.assign({}, ..., ...)` method but it did not help.
3. Arrow functions cannot be used in methods for reactive objects. If I remove the arrow function and put the body inside `.then(function(data) {...})` it complains that `this` is not defined for the second `then` function on `fetch`

```js
// --- src/components/AppraisalView.vue
<script setup>
  import ItemView from './ItemView.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="app_data">{{app_data.items.length}} items in appraisal</div>
  <div v-else>Enter link to get quote</div>
</template>


<script>
  import {Appraisal} from '../stores/Appraisal.js';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        app_data: Appraisal.app_data,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

```js
// ---- src/store/Appraisal.js
import {reactive} from 'vue'
import {BuybackCalculator} from './BuybackCalculator.js';

export const Appraisal = reactive({
  link: '',
  app_data: undefined,
  methods: {
    setLink(value) {
      if (this.link == value) return;

      this.link = value;
      console.log('Updating appraisal with: '+this.link);
      fetch(this.link+".json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.app_data = data;
          console.log(this.app_data);
          BuybackCalculator.methods.calculate_buyback(this.app_data);
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The question should explicitly mention that you use V2 because it can matter when it comes to reactivity. The problem is likely this, `app_data: Appraisal.app_data`. You're disabling reactivity here. If you expect app_data to be updated in a component, it should be a computed. I'm not sure what's the problem with `this`, but it's wrong to use `methods` with `reactive`. It's not a component.

Comment: The `this` context of `methods.setLink` is `methods` not `Appraisal`. There is no need to nest methods in `methods`.